# How to capture returned errorlevel of a sub-batch file and proceed accordingly

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

I am working on a batch file that calls 4 other batch files. If the sub-batch file returns with an errorlevel code other than 0, I want the parent batch file to capture it, send out an email and exit the parent batch file. However, as soon as the first child batch file is called and returns with a non-zero errorlevel, none of the subsequent commands in the parent batch file run. Here is my batch code:

```
rem ** setup so it logs itself **
set parent=%~dp0
set me=%~n0
set LOGFILE=%parent%logs\%me%.log 2>&1
if exist "%LOGFILE%" del %LOGFILE% /f /s /q
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit

:LOG
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS EnableDelayedExpansion

echo ParentDir: %parent%
echo ProgramName: %me%
echo.

rem ** script variables **

set batFile1=%parent%FILE1.bat
set batFile2=%parent%FILE2.bat
set batFile3=%parent%FILE3.bat
set batFile4=%parent%FILE4.bat

set FromEmail=server@domain.com
set Recipient=adminuser@domain.com
set CCRecipient= 

set Subject=Email Subject
set Message=There was an error in running nightly batch files. Please look at the logs to determine which batch file is causing a problem. \n\nAt your service\nAdmin

set Server=smtp.domain.com
set Port=25


rem ** run bat files and capture error message **

echo.
echo Start: Send Email
set Message=Debug test code
c:\APPS\sendemail.exe -f %FromEmail% -t %Recipient% -cc %CCRecipient% -u "%Subject%" -m "%Message%" -v -s %Server%

call %batFile1%

set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%

echo %exitcode%

echo.
echo Start: Send Email
set Message=Debug test code !exitcode!
c:\APPS\sendemail.exe -f %FromEmail% -t %Recipient% -cc %CCRecipient% -u "%Subject%" -m "%Message%" -v -s %Server%

if %exitcode% NEQ 0 (

        echo.
        set Message=Execution of !batFile1! failed with error message !errorcode!. Examine the logs and fix any issues before next run.\n\nAt your service\nAdmin
        echo Start: Send Email
        c:\APPS\sendemail.exe -f !FromEmail! -t !Recipient! -cc !CCRecipient! -u "!Subject!" -m "!Message!" -v -s !Server!

        rem ** force execution to quit if check fails
        EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
)

call %batFile2%

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (

        echo.
        set Message=Execution of %batFile2% failed with error message %ERRORLEVEL%. Examine the logs and fix any issues before next run.\n\nAt your service\nAdmin
        echo Start: Send Email
        c:\APPS\sendemail.exe -f %FromEmail% -t %Recipient% -cc %CCRecipient% -u "%Subject%" -m "%Message%" -v -s %Server%

        rem ** force execution to quit if check fails
        EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
)

call %batFile3%

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (

        echo.
        set Message=Execution of %batFile3% failed with error message %ERRORLEVEL%. Examine the logs and fix any issues before next run.\n\nAt your service\nAdmin
        echo Start: Send Email
        c:\APPS\sendemail.exe -f %FromEmail% -t %Recipient% -cc %CCRecipient% -u "%Subject%" -m "%Message%" -v -s %Server%

        rem ** force execution to quit if check fails
        EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
)

call %batFile4%

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (

        echo.
        set Message=Execution of %batFile4% failed with error message %ERRORLEVEL%. Examine the logs and fix any issues before next run.\n\nAt your service\nAdmin
        echo Start: Send Email
        c:\APPS\sendemail.exe -f %FromEmail% -t %Recipient% -cc %CCRecipient% -u "%Subject%" -m "%Message%" -v -s %Server%

        rem ** force execution to quit if check fails
        EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
)


EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

It appears that none of the lines of code are executed that follow the command `call %batFile1%`

For information purposes, this is how the `%batFile1%` exits:

`EXIT /B 254`

so that should be coming back with %ERRORLEVEL% 254 every time. the test email that I send just before calling batFile1 works fine.

Comment: To me it looks like  your `c:\APPS\sendemail.exe` fails and exits the batch, What about inserting an `Echo %errorlevel% & pause` at Line:52 Also I'd consider to directly follow th `call %batchfile1%` with a conditional execution `|| (echo fail...)`

Comment: Could you please reduce the code to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

rem ** setup so it logs itself **

set "parent=%~dp0"
set "me=%~n0"
set "LOGFILE=%parent%logs\%me%.log"
if exist "%LOGFILE%" del "%LOGFILE%" /f /s /q
call :LOG > "%LOGFILE%" 2>&1
exit


:LOG
setlocal

echo ParentDir: %parent%
echo ProgramName: %me%
echo.

rem ** script variables **

set batFiles="%parent%FILE1.bat" "%parent%FILE2.bat" "%parent%FILE3.bat" "%parent%FILE4.bat"

set "FromEmail=server@domain.com"
set "Recipient=adminuser@domain.com"
set "CCRecipient="

set "Subject=Email Subject"
set Message=There was an error in running nightly batch files.^
 Please look at the logs to determine which batch file is causing a problem.\n\n^
 At your service\n^
 Admin

set "Server=smtp.domain.com"
set "Port=25"

rem ** Send email test **

echo.
echo Start: Send Email
set Message=Debug test code
c:\APPS\sendemail.exe -f "%FromEmail%" -t "%Recipient%" -cc "%CCRecipient%" -u "%Subject%" -m "%Message%" -v -s "%Server%"

rem ** run bat files and capture error message **

for %%A in (%batFiles%) do (
    call :EMAIL %%A
    if errorlevel 1 exit /b
)
exit /b


:EMAIL
setlocal
echo.

call "%~1"

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo %errorlevel%
    set "exitcode=%errorlevel%"
) else exit /b

rem ** Send email **

if "%~n1" == "FILE1" (
    set "Message=Debug test code %exitcode%"
) else set Message=Execution of '%~1' failed with error message %exitcode%.^
 Examine the logs and fix any issues before next run.\n\nAt your service\nAdmin


echo Start: Send Email
c:\APPS\sendemail.exe -f "%FromEmail%" -t "%Recipient%" -cc "%CCRecipient%" -u "%Subject%" -m "%Message%" -v -s "%Server%"

rem ** force execution to quit if check fails **
if %errorlevel% neq 0 echo Email send error message %errorlevel%.
exit /b
```

With optimizing the code some, to remove duplication etc.
It appears to be working better. I may have accidently fixed it.

Suggest checking `echo %errorlevel%` of the `call` before using
`set`, else `%errorlevel%` is of the `set` command.

None of the new code requires delayed expansion, so remove the
`EnableDelayedExpansion` setting.

Scripts are set to one variable and is used as a file-set,
in a `for` loop.

Many of `set variable=value` are double quoted to avoid any
trailing space issues. Those not, are multiline etc. that
are better without.

The Send Email code is not in a label `:EMAIL` which helped
to merge the duplicate code. It does a check if name `FILE1`
is the argument and uses a different email message to match
your original code.

It will end the script if `sendemail.exe` sets `%errorlevel%`
to not zero, which is later checked in the `for` loop.
If you want to exit on the called child batch-file instead,
change the last line from `exit /b` to `exit /b %exitcode%`.

Note, implicit use of `exit /b` is same as `exit /b %errorlevel%`.
If you prefer the later, update the code to you preference.
The later may require delayed variable expansion if used
in a code block i.e. `(command & exit /b !errorlevel!)`.